# How to create a separate Intellij project from a GitHub repo for another project?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have an old Intellij project, which I continue to develop. From it, I'd like to create a new, independent  project, with its own GitHub repo. I'd also like to remove all the previous commits, except for the last one.

**Question:** What's a clean way to do this?

**Tried:** I've created a "New"  project by cloning the "old" repo.  Trying to share the "new"  project on the GitHub via Intellij gave me the "old" repo url and a warning that the "Remote is already on GitHub". But I'd like to share the  project to a new repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these steps:

1) clone the repo again

```
git clone git://server.com/my-repo1.git
```

Do this in a new location

```
cd /parent_folder
```

then

```
cd /new folder
```

2) Remove all entries and their history, creating a clean git repository that contains only data and history

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter your_dir -- -- all
```

3) Move all your content so it will not conflict with the new repo merge

```
mkdir new_directory/
git mv my_stuff new_directory/
```

4) Commit your changes

```
git commit -m
```

5) go to your repo

```
cd ../my-repo2/
```

6) connect your source repo as a remote using a local reference

```
git remote add repo1 ../my-repo1/
```

7) now fetch that source, create a branch and merge with the destination repo

```
git fetch repo1
git branch repo1 remotes/repo1/master
git merge repo1 --allow-unrelated-histories
```

8) push your changes

```
git remote rm repo1
git branch -d repo1
git push origin master
```

Comment: Makes more sense now, after the edit. Originally, I couldn't get past step 2), as Intellij was giving an error,  about unstaged changes. I ended up manually copying the files (I know, not cool). But I'll try the steps next time I have this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry about that I realized it after running a test run and wanted to make sure I updated this with better instructions. Honestly a manual copy is just as good as long as it works. If you want/need to stay in the git world and truly branch this was the only instruction set I could get to work.